# How to get PPM value from MQ-3?

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors

I tried to build project to detect alcohol with Arduino Uno and an MQ-3 Alcohol sensor.

I already have the `R0` value, but I faced problem here: I don't know how to convert it to PPM or BAC. I already tried some code from tutorial for convert it to BAC but when I gave the sensor alcohol the code gives me a value of `0.00`, and I don't know why.

Here is the code to find `R0` value:

```
void setup()
{
   Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
    float sensor_volt;
    float RS; //  Get the value of RS via in a clear air
    float R0;  // Get the value of R0 via in Alcohol
    float sensorValue;

    for(int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++)
    {
        sensorValue = sensorValue + analogRead(A0);
    }

    sensorValue = sensorValue/100.0;     //get average of reading
    sensor_volt = sensorValue/1024*5.0;
    RS = (5.0-sensor_volt)/sensor_volt; //
    R0 = RS/60.0; // 60 is found using interpolation
    Serial.print("R0 = ");
    Serial.println(R0);
    delay(1000);
}
```

Here is the code to determine `BAC`:

```
float R0= 0.28;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  float sensor_volt;
    float RS_gas; // Get value of RS in a GAS
    float ratio; // Get ratio RS_GAS/RS_air
    float BAC;
    int sensorValue = analogRead(A0);
    sensor_volt=(float)sensorValue/1024*5.0;
    RS_gas = (5.0-sensor_volt)/sensor_volt; // omit *RL

   /*-Replace the name "R0" with the value of R0 in the demo of First Test -*/
    ratio = RS_gas/R0;  // ratio = RS/R0
    float a = pow(ratio, 2);   
    float b = ratio/10;
    BAC = (0.1896*a) - (8.6178*b) + 1.0792 ;  //BAC in mg/L
    Serial.print("BAC = ");
    Serial.println(BAC*0.0001);  //convert to g/dL
    Serial.print("\n\n");
    delay(1000);
}
```

I would to know what's wrong with the code, and if you know how to convert the `R0` values to PPM, please tell me.

Comment: figure 5 in the datasheet shows the relation between the output voltage and PPM value   .... https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/Biometric/MQ-3%20ver1.3%20-%20Manual.pdf ........... you have to use a lookup table to convert the value

Answer (score 4):

A series of `if()` statements and some simple division should be able to provide you with your PPM results.

From the datasheet, [Alcohol Gas Sensor（Model：MQ-3)](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/Biometric/MQ-3%20ver1.3%20-%20Manual.pdf), figure 5 shows the *sensitivity curve*:

[image: Sensitivity curve]

It can be seen here

[image: Sensitivity curve - three regions]

that there are three regions that the curve can be broken into:

1. The relationship is linearly proportional between 2.25 V and 3.25 V
2. Between 3.25 V and 3.8 V there is a curve
3. The relationship is linearly proportional between 3.8 V to 4.25 V

The slope of the straight line regions described in points 1 and 3 can be represented by the use of a constant and the PPM value by a simple division of the voltage by the constant.

The curve from the second part could be:

- approximated by a straight line (thus, once again, using a constant), for simplicity, or;
- more accurately, using a lookup table.

Using a straight line approximation for the curve (shown in lurid green), the graph becomes:

[image: Straight line approximation]

To determine the constant for the three lines simply take two points on each line and use:

> (y<sub>2</sub> - y<sub>1</sub>) / (x<sub>2</sub> - x<sub>1</sub>)

So for region one, assuming (by approximation, 3 V corresponds to 100 ppm and 2.5 V corresponds to 85 ppm (my eye sight may be slightly off here), the slope is

```
(3 - 2.5)/(100-80) = 0.5/20 = 0.025
```

You can calculate the constants for regions two and three in a similar manner (if using a straight line approximation for region two).

Therefore the code would be alomg the lines of

```
const double kRegionOne = 0.025;   // region one constant
const double kRegionTwo = ???;     // region two constant
const double kRegionThree = ???;   // region three constant

int ppm;                           // ppm result

/*
 * your code here
 * ...
 */

if ((sensor_volt < 3.25) && (sensor_volt >= 2.25)) {
  ppm = sensor_volt/kRegionOne;    // we are in region 1
} else if ((sensor_volt < 3.8) && (sensor_volt >= 3.25)) {
  ppm = sensor_volt/kRegionTwo;    // we are in region 2
} else if (sensor_volt >= 3.8) {
  ppm = sensor_volt/kRegionThree;  // we are in region 3
}
```

If you wish to be more accurate then use a lookup table for region two, as jsotola states in [their comment](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/54534/how-to-get-ppm-value-from-mq-3/54543#comment114452_54534).